# Tracking down the source of handle leaks in WinSock MFC application

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc, memory-leaks, winsock

We are developing an application in which we are using a WinSock-based sime socket approach to communicate with an outside module. Our requirement is to make sure that the connection will always be on, so for that reason, we continuously retry to connect every 1 minute whenever we get disconnected.

Our problem starts here. We have observered that on every retry of socket reconnect, it is leaking exactly two Windows handles. We have tried so many options, but none of them are working. Which handles could be leaking, and how could we go about identifying the culprit?

Following is the code that we are using right now:

```
bool CSocketClass::ConnectToServer(int nLineNo)
{
string strIPAddress;
int nPortNo;
SOCKET* l_ClientSocket;
int ConnectionResult;
//----------------------
// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
if (nLineNo == 1)   
     {
    m_objLine1.m_ClientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    strIPAddress = m_objLine1.m_strIPAddress;
    nPortNo = m_objLine1.m_nPortNo;
    l_ClientSocket = &(m_objLine1.m_ClientSocket);
}
else
{
    m_objLine2.m_ClientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    strIPAddress = m_objLine2.m_strIPAddress;
    nPortNo = m_objLine2.m_nPortNo;
    l_ClientSocket = &(m_objLine2.m_ClientSocket);
}
if(INVALID_SOCKET == *l_ClientSocket)
{
    return false;
}
//----------------------
// The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
// IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.
sockaddr_in clientService;
clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( strIPAddress.c_str() );
clientService.sin_port = htons( nPortNo );
//----------------------
// Connect to server.
ConnectionResult = connect( *l_ClientSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) ) ;  if (ConnectionResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    if (nLineNo == 1)
    {
        //ERROR in line1
    }
    else
    {
        //ERROR in line2
    }
    return false;
}
else
//In case of successful connection
{

    //Other actions
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: Your leak isn't in the posted code. As a side note, don't `closesocket(INVALID_SOCKET)` - that's pointless at best and damaging at worst.

Comment: Initially we were closing sockets only if its connected, but even that was not solving our purpose.. Are you sure leak is not in this code? Because I have literally seen (while debugging) that after connect statement my code is leaking exactly 2 handles.. And just to make it sure I am talking about windows handle leaks that we can see in task manager, I am not talking about memory leaks.

Comment: @vrajs5: You're not closing these sockets when you're done with them. It's not a leak when you connect - it becomes a leak when you forget to clean up.

Comment: @vrajs5: Did you e.g. close the old sockets before calling this function?

Comment: @Erik : We call these function if old socket disconnected.. And just for safty we are closing that old socket and after that we are calling this function.. I know what you are trying to say it leaks when its not getting cleared.. But we are calling closesocket before reconnection..

Comment: @vrajs5: Well, there's no problem in this piece of code - you're just creating a socket and connecting.

Comment: How do you handle disconnection events? You might be leaking a whole Socket.

Comment: @nxzdr I am closing socket only if previously connected socket became invalid.... And in our application we never disconnect socket while its running. Only if server socket get disconnected we will create new socket.

Comment: I posted my answer, but having read these comments, are you sure you should trust Task Manager's handle count?  Might there not be some caching where it deliberately doesn't reduce the handle count?

Comment: @vrajs5 When the server disconnects, you probably forgot to release the sockets, and simply created new ones and ran the reconnect code.

Answer (score 3):

Try the free [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) from Microsoft.  It will display all the open handles for a process along with information such as name (for file, mutex, event, etc. handles).  It will also highlight newly created and closed handles, so if you step through a loop of your code and refresh the display, you can see the exact handles that were leaked.

Comment: +1 Process Explorer is great, another option would be to use the "handle" tool also from sysinternals to check which handles are open

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you acquired socket correctly:

```
m_objLine1.m_ClientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) 
m_objLine1.m_ClientSocket != INVALID_SOCKET // true
```

but then, you can't connect, so

```
ConnectionResult = connect( *l_ClientSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService,
    sizeof(clientService) ) 
ConnectionResult == SOCKET_ERROR // true
```

in that case, you should close that acquired socket handle:

```
closesocket(m_objLine1.m_ClientSocket);
```

You have two lines, so I guess that you call this function twice, once for each line, so 
that's why two leaked handles.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try [Intel Parallel Inspector](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-parallel-inspector/) in order to identify the memory leaks and where they are occurring.

There is a trial download if you wish to try it.

Comment: Are you talking about memory leak inspectors? Because I am talking about handle leaks...

Comment: Intel Parallel Inspector is able to detect leaking windows handles as well. I have used it to find leaking GDI handles, I assume it would work the same for socket handles.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to find handle leaks is to log everything.

Every time you obtain a handle, log that you obtained it, as well as any other details about the circumstances.  Every time you release a handle, log that you released it.  Include both times the actual handle (just some hex).

Then you get a log that looks like this (just for example):

```
Obtained handle 0xf000 (nLineNo = 5)
Obtained handle 0xb000 (nLineNo = 6)
Obtained handle 0xd0d0 (nLineNo = 7)
Released handle 0xf000
Released handle 0xb000
```

Picking through this by hand, you can see that you obtained handle 0xd0d0 when nLineNo was 7, and it never got released.  It's not much but it does help, and if the going gets tough, you can even try logging stack traces at each obtain/release.  Also, if the log is always reliably produced like that, you can start putting in breakpoints based on the actual values (e.g. break at a point in the program when the handle is 0xd0d0, so you can see what's happening to it).

If it's more practical, you can start wrapping your handles inside the program itself, e.g. a `std::set` of all obtained handles, along with any details about when they were obtained, and you can effectively start hacking your program to keep track of what it's doing (then undo all your changes once you fixed it).

Hope that helps - it's part of the reason I tend to at least keep a `std::set` of everything I obtain, so if worst comes to worst you can iterate over them on shutdown and release them all (and log a big "FIX THIS!" message!)

Comment: I am not obtaining handles manually/directly..I am just creating socket and closing it.. I am also logging open and close events (its not there in this code) But that doesnt solve our problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `shutdown(SD_BOTH)` on the socket handles after the `closesocket();` Also, try adding a Sleep for about 100ms (only for a test) and see how it goes.