# Leaking Handles when using Microsoft Remote Desktop Client

Tags: memory-leaks, remote-desktop, mstsc, handle-leak

I am utilizing the *AxMSTSCLib.dll* to embed the **MSTSC Client** into a WPF-Control.


Everything is working as expected, but: Each successful "[Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/imstscax-connect)-[Disconnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/imstscax-disconnect)" cycle, the **Process.HandleCount** increases and leaks memory:
[image: Leak in Action]
They are never garbage collected in runtime. They leak only on successful Connections, so I suspect there must be some leftover File- or TCP-Stream but I still have a hard time finding, accessing and manipulating those unmanaged resources

### Reproduction Code

To set up the stripped core of the project:

1. Open Visual Studio and create a "WPF App (.Net Framework)" project named "RemoteClientHandleLeak"
2. Add these 4 References:

   - Assemblies: ***System.Windows.Forms*** and ***WindowsFormsIntegration***
   - Browse: ***AxMSTSCLib.dll*** and ***MSTSCLib.dll*** located at:
      *C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\14.0\AxMSTSCLib.dll*
     ...and set their *'Embed Interop Types'* property to False (this should set *'Copy Local'* to True)
3. Paste this into *MainWindow.xaml*:

```
<Window x:Class="RemoteClientHandleLeak.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="830" Height="535" >
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#cccdd1">
        <Button x:Name="Start" Content="Start" Click="Click_StartSequence" Margin="10,3,685,466" />
        <Button x:Name="Stop" Content="Stop" Click="Click_StopSequence" Margin="274,3,421,466" />
        <Button x:Name="Probe" Content="Probe Handles" Click="Click_Probe" Margin="496,3,199,466" />
        <Button x:Name="ForceGC" Content="Force GC" Click="Click_ForceGC" Margin="628,3,67,466" />
        <Button x:Name="StartAlt" Content="Start (no connect)" Click="Click_StartSequenceAlt" Margin="142,3,553,466" />
        <Grid x:Name="parentGrid" Width="800" Height="450" Margin="10,42,10,10"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

4. Paste this into *MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Text;

using RdpClient = AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting;
using FormHost = System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost;

namespace RemoteClientHandleLeak
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string memLogPath = @"C:\Marrt\logWpf_RemoteDesktopClient.txt";
        private const string srv = "192.168.1.15", usr = "remote", pwd = "remote";
        private int connectionDurationMs = 200;

        private bool trackDisposalState = true;
        List<WeakReference> hostHistory = new List<WeakReference>();
        List<WeakReference> clientHistory = new List<WeakReference>();


        public async Task MySequence()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var task1 = LeakDemonstration();
                await Task.WhenAll(task1);
                ProbeWeakRef();
                MemoryStamp();
                if (stop) { return; }
            }
        }

        public async Task LeakDemonstration()
        {
            using (var winFormHost = new FormHost())
            using (var axMsRdpClient = new RdpClient())
            {
                if(trackDisposalState){
                    hostHistory.Add(new WeakReference(winFormHost, false));
                    clientHistory.Add(new WeakReference(axMsRdpClient, false));
                }

                winFormHost.Child = axMsRdpClient;
                parentGrid.Children.Add(winFormHost);
                ApplyClientSetting(axMsRdpClient, (int)parentGrid.ActualWidth, (int)parentGrid.ActualHeight);

                if (!skipConnect){
                    //LEAKING HANDLES!
                    axMsRdpClient.Connect();
                    await Task.Delay(connectionDurationMs);
                    axMsRdpClient.Disconnect();
                } else {
                    //no leak, perfectly clean disposal
                    await Task.Delay(connectionDurationMs);
                }
                await Task.Delay(120);

                parentGrid.Children.Clear();// same as parentGrid.Children.Remove(winFormHost);
            }
        }


        private void ApplyClientSetting(RdpClient client, int w, int h)
        {
            //client.Domain = "";
            client.Server = srv;
            client.UserName = usr;
            client.AdvancedSettings2.ClearTextPassword = pwd;
            client.AdvancedSettings7.EnableCredSspSupport = true;

            //client.ColorDepth = 16;
            client.DesktopWidth = w;
            client.DesktopHeight = h;

            client.ConnectingText = "Connecting...";
            client.ConnectedStatusText = "Connected";
            client.DisconnectedText = "Offline";
        }

        #region  Helper & UI
        private void ProbeWeakRef()
        {
            int hCount = hostHistory.Count, cCount = clientHistory.Count, hAlive = 0, cAlive = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < hostHistory.Count; i++)
            {
                hAlive += hostHistory[i].IsAlive ? 1 : 0;
                cAlive += hostHistory[i].IsAlive ? 1 : 0;
            }

            using (var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"WeakRefs: host.IsAlive:{hAlive}/{hCount} client.IsAlive:{cAlive}/{cCount}; HandleCount:{process.HandleCount}");
            }
        }

        public void MemoryStamp()
        {
            using (var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append($"{ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd\tHH:mm:ss.ffff")}\tMemory\t");
                sb.Append($"{process.PeakWorkingSet64}\t{process.PrivateMemorySize64}\t{process.WorkingSet64}\t{GC.GetTotalMemory(true).ToString("#.,###")}\t{process.HandleCount}\n");
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText( memLogPath, sb.ToString());   //Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();
            }
        }

        private void ForceGarbageCollection()
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            ProbeWeakRef();
        }

        public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }
        private bool stop;
        private bool skipConnect;

        private void Click_StartSequence(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { stop = false; skipConnect = false; Task seq = MySequence(); }
        private void Click_StartSequenceAlt(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { stop = false; skipConnect = true; Task seq = MySequence(); }
        private void Click_StopSequence(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { stop = true; }
        private void Click_Probe(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { ProbeWeakRef(); }
        private void Click_ForceGC(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { ForceGarbageCollection(); }

        #endregion  Helper & UI
    }
}
```

5. Modify the connection settings (host must be reachable and login valid for leaks to occur)
   [image: Connection Settings]
6. Finally, Press Start (=10 Connect-Disconnect Cycles) and observe them Handles leaking
   [image: Button]
   [image: Handles]

I have tried countless things in the last weeks, all have those leaking handles:

- Winform-only Project (without above async function automation)
- Tried many suspicious [AdvancedSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/imsrdpclientadvancedsettings-interface), [AdvancedSettings2-7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/imsrdpclientadvancedsettings7)
- Visual Studio Memory Profiler with Snapshot difference (hints at TCP-Stream Handle)
- Disposing
- [Closing Handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225945/how-to-release-a-handle-through-c)
- trying *Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Object)* on various things
- Object.Finalize() pattern (not sure if I did it right)
- ResourceManager.ReleaseAllResources() on rdp.GetOcx()
- connecting to other OS (xrdp on unix)
- [this sounded familiar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/mstscax-dll-file-leaks-handles-on-a-remote-desktop-protocol-8-1-client-in-windows-7-or-windows-server-2008-r2-a7899e54-1e11-4042-7678-7435175c53a3)
- i haven't tried [AppDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63616618/how-to-dynamically-load-and-unload-reload-a-dll-assembly) reloading yet
- i am on *Windows 10* using *.Net Framework 4.7.2*

Comment: I just downloaded and tried these projects and they seem to have the same Handle Leak
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19836/Palantir-Remote-Desktop-Manager
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET

Comment: This also sounds like a hot lead:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662798/tracking-down-the-source-of-handle-leaks-in-winsock-mfc-application

Comment: I suspect this Handle leak even happens when using the native mstsc.exe (simulated Connect-Disconnect by pulling out and replugging the cable)

Comment: I was able to locate the Hotfix mentioned in above "this sounded familiar" link: 'https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb3042836' I extracted the mstscax.dll from there and cheated it into the project. Low and behold: the Leak seems to be fixed in that DLL, the Handles stay constant. But I have to run some more tests to be sure. But it seems that they hotfixed a Handle-Leak in Win7 and Win8 for some server use-cases but didn't propagate the fix in the Win10 DLLs

Comment: Im having the same problem, how did you extract it? I can't seem to find that dll in the hotfix

Comment: I opened the hotfix with with 7z. Then used the "expand" command to extract the .cab content (i think i had to do this two or three times in subfolders) until you get the x64 mstscax.dll (File and Product version 6.3.9600.17794). Beware that you need very specific settings in visual studio so that the supplied .dll is taken and not the locally installed.

Comment: @timeshift, If you succeed, pls let us know how you did it. Currently i have to manually overwrite the mstscax.dll that gets compiled into the build path. It uses the host's locally installed mstscax.dll by default. This is fine for my deployed .exe, but i also use this as WPF-Plugin, and the Hostapplication also puts the Host's mstscax.dll into its DLL-Cache folder where i can't overwrite it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in the comments below the original question:
**This is demonstrably a Bug in Microsoft's MSTSC Client**.

I have set up a **Win8.1**x64 system with and without the hotfix (hinted at in [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/mstscax-dll-file-leaks-handles-on-a-remote-desktop-protocol-8-1-client-in-windows-7-or-windows-server-2008-r2-a7899e54-1e11-4042-7678-7435175c53a3) Microsoft article) ...and these are the graphs for the connection cycles:
[image: Graph]
That means in Win8.1+Hotfix there is no leak!

So how can i get this [Hotfix](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb3042836) into Win10?
-> I tried using the fixed mtscax.dll which extracted from the Win8.1 Hotfix within Win10, but that seems fishy. Additionally, while my tests in Win10 have no Handle Leaks, they are leaking GDI-Handles now (which is worse). So there must be some incompatibility.